# parsing string in c# and putting them into variables

Tags: c#, arrays, string, parsing, char

Hello everyone I am a student and still learning C#. I need to parse a string having this format:

```
< test, 1, 0, 1>
```

How can I extract the word `test`, and the numbers `1`, `0`, and `1`, to put them in variables in their proper datatypes?

I tried to convert it to a `string` and then use `Substring()` and `IndexOf()` and `Split()`, but non of them worked.

```c
//this is what i did in c but i cant do it in c#
void parseData() {      // split the data into its parts

    char * strtokIndx; // this is used by strtok() as an index

    strtokIndx = strtok(tempChars,",");      // get the first part - the string
    strcpy(messageFromPC, strtokIndx); // copy it to messageFromPC

    strtokIndx = strtok(NULL, ","); // this continues where the previous call left off
    com1 = atoi(strtokIndx);     // convert this part to an integer

    strtokIndx = strtok(NULL, ",");
    com2 = atoi(strtokIndx);     

    strtokIndx = strtok(NULL, ","); 
    com3 = atoi(strtokIndx);     

    //strtokIndx = strtok(NULL, ",");
    //com4 = atof(strtokIndx);     
}
```

Comment: What _exactly_ does the string look like? `"<test,1,0,1>"` or `"test,1,0,1"`? I mean are the `<` and `>` part of the string or did you just add them to mark the string?

Comment: @RenéVogt it is intended to be part of the string because it marks the begining and ending of it.

Comment: ok, updated my answer accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a comma-separated string you can use `string.Split()`:

```
string input = "<test, 1, 0, 1>";

// first remove the < and >
string inputWithoutBrackets = input.TrimStart('<').TrimEnd('>');

// split the string at the commas
string[] parts = inputWithoutBrackets.Split(',');

string messageFromPC = parts[0].Trim(); // use Trim to get rid of whitespaces
int com1 = int.Parse(parts[1].Trim());
int com2 = int.Parse(parts[2].Trim());
int com3 = int.Parse(parts[3].Trim());
```

Be sure to add error handling (`parts` may have less then 4 entries if the string did not have enough `,`. `int.Parse` may throw exceptions if there is no parseable number).

---

A note about strings in C#: They are *immutable* reference types. So every operation on a string returns a **new** string instead of manipulating the current instance. E.g. `Trim` does not trim the current instance, but *returns* the trimmed string.

Answer (score -1):

This sounds like a homework/learning assignment and we do not provide code for those. Usually that part is integral to the learning experience. What we can do is give you general ideas.

parse a string in this format < test, 1, 0, 1>. how can i extract the word "test", and "1", "0", "1"

The proper Data Type would be 1 string, 3 integers for this specific example. There is not much you can generalize about this. .NET is strongly typed at compile time. While it has interop for weakly typed things (like interaction with XML WebServices), those are decidedly advanced.

Splitting the string is relatively speaking the hard part of the problem. I can think of at least these solutions:

- string.Split(","), after cutting of any leading and trailing "<", ">" and " "
- Using a CSV parser for it (especially if this is not the only line)
- using regular Expressions (REGEX)
- Doing the splitting up manually via a for-loop itterating over the characters and storing each one into one element of a `string[]`.

As the <> are part of the markers, the CSV parser and REGEX seem like the most likely tools to use. But it really depends on what you learned before. Usually such tasks are there to reinforce what you previously were taugth.

Comment: its part of my project thesis actually, And yes it is the hardest part. I am asking this because it will be the communication line between arduino and c#. I am still learning C# and Regex seems to be a good option for this. thankyou :)